# React Native Transparent Video

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I have a problem where I need to play 2 videos on top of each other, one of them is a transparent video and the other is a normal video. So starting from there, I would like to play the original video and than on top of that play the transparent video, both videos should be synced with each other. Does someone know if that is possible or not. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

@EkremAy thank you for your feedback but I think you should double check your answer, because videos with aplha channel exist, they have .webm or .mov extensions (not sure for other extensions, but I'm 100% sure that .mp4 files to not support transparent videos), also you can check this [link](https://codepen.io/xy_r/pen/JjodVvB) for a reference.

I got a demo working on ReactJs where I have a .mp4 video and .webm video and everything works as it should (I will attach the code below), I will try to implement it on React Native and if I find a solution for react native as well I will edit this question so someone else might use it.

```
import video from './assets/counter.mp4'
import alpha from './assets/alpha.webm'

const VideoDemo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Transparent video on top a video DEMO</p>
      <video height="700" width="1000" muted autoPlay controls style={{ zIndex: '-1', position: 'absolute'}}>
        <source src={video} type="video/mp4"/>
      
      </video>
      <video height="600" width="1000" muted autoPlay controls = '' >
          <source src={alpha}type="video/webm"/>
        </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoDemo;
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the background of the video is green(like green screen), this color can be removed to make it appear transparent. If you can emulate this process on react-native, you can play videos on top of each other but it is quite difficult to implement.

For an easier start, you can put videos in 2 different `<View>`s and change their size and `opacity` settings. It's not exactly what you imagined, but it will show you where to focus.

Comment: Transparent videos exist. Since they are composed by images and images can be transparent why not videos ? .webm is one of the types that supports it along with avi flv f4v and quicktime they aupport alpha (transparency)

Without doing rocket science with the green background.

Comment: @em.rexhepi Thanks for informing me, I'll update my answer.